# Razor addDays doesn't work

Tags: sql, razor

i'll start with the code and explain after.

```
var inputDate = "2016-12-27";

var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE date = '" + inputDate + "'";
```

.

```
<body>
    @{ 
        var sumKG = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        sumKG += total;

    }
    @sumKG
</body>
```

So this will take all the data that has the `inputDate` and sum up a few things to `sumKG`,  but after that I want it to run the loop again on the next day, in this case 2016-12-28, (this wont be hardcoded in the future, this is just for test).

I found that `.addDays(1)` would be a solution but I cant make it work, it doesn't exist in my intellisense either. So I don't know how I use it or how to make it update the date since that part of the code isn't inside the loop so I'm not sure how to change it?

Does anyone know of a solution that would fit?

Comment: Google "SQL Injection"

Comment: 1. Never use string concatination with sql statements, always use parameters. 2. Do not query directly in your view, do it in the controller.

Comment: Ye thanks! This page will never be online and im not doing a MVC project, this little site im doing was to small for me to learn MVC which was a huuuge headache for me

Comment: I tried to give MVC a shot like 2-3 times but man, didnt make any sense to me

Comment: But I will take my time and learn about these sql injections!

Comment: @PontusSvedberg Being online or not is not an excuse to use concatenated SQL.  It's easy to implement, and a good habit to get into. Concatenated SQL can lead to a lot of SQL Injection issues (whether malicious or through valid data) where queries aren't constructed correctly due to the string being injected.